# Applications in Anaconda have to be installed after every start

Tags: python, anaconda, rstudio

Anaconda somehow behaves quite strangely. When I install an application like RStudio and quite Anaconda and restart Anaconda again, I have to reinstall it again. So there is no "Launch" icon but at "Install" icon. I tried it 5 times and it did not change.

Further, when starting Anaconda I get the message that a new version of Anaconda Navigator is available and I am asked to update it. When clicking on "Yes" literally nothing happen except that the Dialog window disappears.

I ran Anaconda both as an Admin and not Admin but the behaviour is always the same. I even unistalled Anaconda and re-installed it but this also did not change anything.

Does someone have an idea what the problem is with my Anaconda (my OS is Win 10). I'd appreciate every comment.

What would you advice me to do because it is really inconvenient to install an Application every time I use Anaconda. It this behaviour even usual for Anaconda? I can't imagine that.

Reminder: Does anyone have an idea? What would you suggest me to do. I'd appreciate every comment, even if you are unsure.

I tried a lot and still could not find a solution. Does really nobody of the Anaconda users have an idea?

Update: I installed 5 different versions of Anaconda and all of them seem to be buggy. They all have the problem of updating the navigator and in some you can't even install R Studio (I waited 2 hours but the 'installation' was still in 'progress'). On some you could install R Studio but when starting Anaconda again you had to re-install it every time.  I tried many different versions (x_86 and x_86_64) from different years. I tried it with and without Admin privileges. The problem with R Studio and updating the Navigatior exist in every version. What could be the problem and what else can I do? I'd highly appreciate any further comment and idea and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: The update window disappear on clicking Yes and nothing happen later, also happens with me. I think its bug in current version and it will be fixed by manually downloading and installing Anaconda from Anaconda Website.

Comment: Thanks  thisisjaymehta for your answer. As written in the post I unistalled Anaconda and installed the latest version from the website but nothing changed at all. Further, Anaconda has many problems (I have to install some applications like R Studio after every start which is quite incovenient). I have somehow the impression that Anaconda itself tends to be buggy. But I can't solve the issues. Maybe the software quality of Anaconda is low? I have not experienced such big problems with any programming environment during the last 10 years to be totally honest

Comment: Yes. I also have the latest version. I think they will fix it in new versions.
To help with your RStudio problem, maybe try older versions of Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks  thisisjaymehta for your further answer and effort. I really appreciate your comments. So you also have this issue with RStudio? How can I dowload older versions of Anaconda? I just know this site: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual and there you can only download the latest version as far as I see it. Further, do you really think that an older version will be better. I somehow have the impression that Anacondas quality is quite low and if i use an even older version it might be even worse? What do you think? I'd appreciate if you could share your experience

Comment: I have not encountered the problem with RStudio because I don't use it. But I do have the update problem. But apart from problems we are facing, Anaconda is very good product. I mainly use Jupyter and Spider in Anaconda and I like how it makes it easy to make and manage environments. Anyway, as I said you should try old version and see if problem is solved. Here is link to [archive of anaconda](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/)

Comment: Thanks  thisisjaymehta  for your comments and effort. I really appreciate it. I now installed an old version of Anaconda and here I do not have the problem with launchingm R Studio (but the problem with updating the Anaconda Navigator still persists). Now when I start Spyder 3.2 I get an recommendation for an update to Spyder 4.2 stating that I should not use pip and Anaconda to update but I should wait for new conda packages. How can I do that?

Comment: Is means that you should not updated Spyder manually but update Anaconda which in turn update Spyder. But as you know latest Anaconda will have problems with RStudio in your PC. I suggest using old version of Anaconda till new update isn't release. And use old version of Spyder too. If you want new version of Spyder, try manually upgrading it ignoring the warning.

Comment: Thanks a lot  thisisjaymehta for your comments and efforts. How do I know about a new version of Anaconda? According to the site you gave me the link to the last update was in November 2018? So is Anaconda not updated anymore and wherefrom can I get to know when a new version is ready? Maybe it will not take that long because the current version seems to be extremely buggy.

Comment: Please look closely, the dates are not sorted. Last version was released very recently and not in 2018.

Comment: Thanks a lot thisisjaymehta for your comments and efforts. I installed 5 different versions of Anaconda and allo of them are buggy. The all have the problem of updating the navigator and in some you can't even install R Studio (I waited 2 hours but the 'installation' was still in 'progress'). On some you could install R Studio but when starting Anaconda again you had to re-install it every time. Did not know that Anaconda has to ridiciously bad software quality. I am wondering why still so many use it

Comment: Any idea what the problem might be? As said before, I tried many different versions (x_86 and x_86_64) from different years. I tried it with and without Admin privileges. The problem with R Studio and updating the Navigatior exist in every version.

Answer (score 1):

When you install R Studio in Anaconda, it creates a new environment called rstudio. When you close and open Anaconda, it generally goes to the root environment. You need to select the rstudio environment in order to see R-Studio installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On the top left corner of the Anaconda navigator, you will find two dropdowns(one for applications and the other for environment).

On the second dropdown, find 'rstudio'(or any name during RStudio installation). Then you might see the 'Launch' icon in the RStudio tile.

Have attached a screenshot.

[image]